# How to access individual frames of an animated GIF loaded into a ID3D11ShaderResourceView?

Tags: c++, directx, imgui, directxtk

I used [CreateWICTextureFromFile()](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader#createwictexturefromfile) from DirectXTK to load an animated GIF texture.

```
ID3D11Resource* Resource;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* View;
hr = CreateWICTextureFromFile(d3dDevice, L"sample.gif",
    &Resource, &View);
```

Then I displayed it on an `ImageButton` in dear IMGUI library:

```
ImGui::ImageButton((void*)View, ImVec2(width, height));
```

But it only displays a still image (the first frame of the GIF file).

I think I have to give it the texture of each frame separately. But I don't know how. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CreateWICTextureFromFile` function in *DirectX Tool Kit* (a.k.a. the 'light-weight' version in the [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) module) only loads a single 2D texture, not multi-frame images like animated GIF or TIFF.

The [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) function **LoadFromWICFile** can load multiframe images if you give it the `WIC_FLAGS_ALL_FRAMES` flag. Because the library is focused on DirectX resources, it will resize them all to match the first image size.

That said, what WIC is going to return to you is a bunch of raw frames. You have query the metadata from WIC to actually get the animation information, and it's a little complicated to reconstruct. I have a simple implementation in the *DirectXTex* [texassemble](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble) tool you can reference [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/Texassemble/AnimatedGif.cpp). I focused on converting the animated GIF into a 'flip-book' style 2D texture array which is quite a bit larger.

> The sample I referenced can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicanimatedgif)